# Invariance under charge conjugation... Or not?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electroweak, charge-conjugation

I have read some paper which says that the electroweak Lagrangian includes these terms like
$\bar{\psi} \gamma_a\gamma_5\psi$ and $\bar{\psi} \gamma_a \psi$.
They violate charge conjugation symmetry. I understand the violation of the first term, but I did not get whether the second term violates or does not violate the charge symmetry.
$$
C \bar{\psi} \gamma_a\gamma_5\psi C = -? \bar{\psi} \gamma_a\gamma_5\psi 
$$ 
But some paper and books this sign $+$ some paper $-$. Which one is correct?

Comment: Please try to use titles which give the reader some idea what the question is about. [Here are some tips](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles).

Comment: The latter. ...

Answer (score 0):

The electroweak Lagrangian contains terms which are not eigenstates of $P$, but (to good approximation) only terms which are eigenstates of $T$. Since $CPT$ is an exact symmetry, the electroweak Lagrangian must contain terms which are not eigenstates of $C$.